# Getting "Socket in use" error after closing socket and restarting application

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

I am running into an issue with my TCP sockets where they are not closing, even after *apparently* closing them gracefully.

There are time where my application will need to be restarted, and in the process of it being restarted I encounter the error, "Only one usage of each socket address is normally permitted". Meaning the stream or the client is not releasing the socket, if I understand correctly.

My processing logic is as follows:

```
while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
{
   TcpClient newClient;
   NetworkStream newStream;
   try
   {
      // Attempts to connect to the server until it succeeds, or the token is cancelled.
      newClient = await ConnectToServer();
      if (newClient.Connected)
      {
         // This loops until the cancellation token source calls cancel()
         await ProcessData(newStream, token);
      }
   }
   catch
   {
      // Handle errors here
   }
   finally
   {
      newStream.Close();
      newStream.Dispose();
      newClient.Close();
      newClient.Dispose();
   }
}
```

Even after trying to close the client socket directly with `newClient.Client.Close()`, closing both the stream and the socket, closing just the stream alone, and other combinations that I could think of... it is still not working. I have also tried the using directive on the TCPClient/NetworkStream. Nothing seems to work. I have also done what [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51215320/what-should-i-do-to-completely-close-the-tcpclient-connection-with-mcu) has suggested, but to no success.

The framework I am using is 4.8.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: From cms.exe use Netstat -a to see status of the connections on both the server and client.  Connections should always be closed from client ONLY.  When you close simultaneously from both client and server you have a raise condition and the socket does not fully close.  TCP is reliable which means every message has an ACK.  If both client and server both close at same time one end doesn't receive the ACK and the connection doesn't fully close.  Then you cannot open a new connection.

Comment: Thank you for the netstat suggestion. The socket appears to go into the "TIME_WAIT" status. I don't know what that means, but I will try and find out.
Also I have edited the question for clarity, as I am not the server in this situation. I am receiving data from the server, and the server stays online the whole time.

Comment: Looks like I'm right.  It is waiting for an ACK that never occurs.  See : http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/01/time-wait-and-its-design-implications-for-protocols-and-scalable-servers.html

Comment: Yeah, you were right. Thank you for that link, it is really helpful. It looks like the process of trying to close the sockets gracefully is forcing them into a TIME_WAIT status. The fix, apparently, is to not attempt to close them and allow the closing of the application to send the RST flag to force close the application. You helped a lot, so if you wanna take the answer, I'll mark it as accepted. If not I'll put something together. Thank you again for the help.

Comment: The correct solution is not to close the connection on the listener.  If you just close the connection from the client then the connection will full close by itself.